# how do I drop NA within pandas.DataFrame.query

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[-1, 0, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, 4]))
```

I can drop NA like this

```
df.dropna()
```

[image]

but how do I do it within the `query` method

```
df.query('A is not null')
```

doesn't work... what does?

Comment: I think you're a go to open an issue on github...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea #2: what's distinctive about NaNs is that they're not equal to themselves:

```
In [22]: df.query("A == A")
Out[22]: 
     A
0 -1.0
1  0.0
2  1.0
4  2.0
6  3.0
7  4.0
```

(The original idea #1 was to use `df.query("A.notnull()")`, but that only worked because `numexpr` wasn't installed in that environment, which limits the usefulness of `query` in the first place.)

Comment: Idea #1 brings this for me: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @Boud: huh, works for me with both 0.18.1 and 0.19.0.

Comment: I have deep affection for A = A

Comment: It's interesting -  Idea #1 gives me the same error as @Boud has reported. I have Pandas 0.19.0, numexpr: 2.6.1. What is your numexpr version?

Comment: Same error for me.  I just did the full anaconda install a week ago so I have totally stock anaconda except for updating pandas to 0.19.0

Comment: I think I know what happened-- those venvs didn't have numexpr installed, so it just delegated the call!  Since lots of people probably use query for the potential performance benefits (not just the syntax cleanup), that's probably not going to be that common a situation in practice.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

`DataFrame.query` method is based on `pandas.eval` interpreter. `null` is not defined in there. Similarly neither `None` nor `is`. However, you can use this hackish method:

```
df.query('A < inf')
```

Luckily the name `inf` is defined and comparisons with it only returns numbers.

Comment: I had pretty much the same idea:  `df.query('abs(A) >= 0')`

Comment: I tried `nan = np.nan ; df.query("A != @nan")` but apparently the test returns True for all values. Weird so far

Answer (score 1):

You could use outer merge and a filter to remove from a DF the elements obtained from the query:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[-1, 0, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, 4]))
not_null_df = df[df.A.notnull()]

new_df = df.merge(not_null_df, how='outer', indicator=True)
new_df = new_df[new_df._merge == 'both']
del new_df['_merge']
```

Comment: I very specifically wanted to use `query`